# Diagonal HTML Map not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help.
I want to implement a Google Maps Map on my webpage.
But not just a normal map, I want it to be diagonal (better described in the picture).

To do this I thought I just create a div, screwY it with css, put the map inside and screwY this also but negative.
Result: The div is like I want it but the map css makes the div appear normal straight.
Like the map css overrides the div attributes.
How can I have them separately? 
It’s really hard to describe, but I hope you understand what I mean.
Code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="diagonal">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

CSS:

```
#diagonal {
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  height: 40vh;
}

#map {
  top: 5em;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50vh;
  transform: skewY(0deg);
}
```

JS:

```
function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap
    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

How I want it Image
[image: How I want it Image]

Comment: Does it have any thing to do with #map : `skewY (0deg)` ¿¿

Comment: Thats what I dont know. If I dont put it in, the map content (font etc) is also skewed. So I have to put it back straight.

Comment: The div is skewed negatively, according to you question, if you skew the map opposite of div, the map will appear straight, that's right.

Comment: The div is skewed negatively, according to you question, if you skew the map opposite of div, the map will appear straight, that's right. Negative+Positive=Neutral

Comment: True. But when I do this, the whole map is straight again and does not have the shape I want it to have. I mean, also the div gets back straight

Comment: Try keeping div straight and skewY the `#map`

Comment: Yes. But then the font isnt straight and you cant read it anymore.

Comment: Well, then try my second thought ¡!¡, create a div and skew it, another div and skew it, finally map and skew it opposite ? Tell me if it works ;)

Comment: No it doesnt. It switches back to a straight div. I can post a Codepen link, so you can try it by your own if you have the time and see if you can fix it.

Comment: okay, post it...

Comment: Ok, cant set up codepen with google maps for some reason. Here is a other editor: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRVWKG2114M7

Comment: It worked for the first time and then whoops.... it's gone, I'm also unable to run it with stack snippets or code pen or even on my PC... did you look the first answer ? Did it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example of using an svg triangle to overlay the top and bottom of the map. You might want to play with the dimentions a bit to get exactly what you want. See it herehttps://codepen.io/DriftDesign/pen/ERPLNj

Here is the svg and css code that applies the effect.

```
// html/svg
        <div class="svg-top-container">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
             <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L100 2 L0 100 Z" stroke-width="0"></path>
           </svg>
         </div>

// css
    .svg-bottom-container {
        fill: #fcfcfc;
    }
    .svg-bottom-container {
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: It's not exactly related to map skewing but it's interesting :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Maybe a dumb question (I'm new to this): I put a svg with the shape I want on my page and let it overlay my map?

Comment: Exactly. It wont skew the map exactly but it should give you exactly what you have in the image.